# How to get post owner with django rest framework

Tags: django-rest-framework

I'am trying to link Posts with the users that make them. in django rest framework, but i seem to be having troubles with it.

this is my model.

```
class RealtorManager(models.Manager):
    def create_profile(self, owner, name, email, description, photo, phone):
        if name is None:
            raise TypeError('Name is required')
        if email is None:
            raise TypeError('email is required')
        if phone is None:
            raise TypeError('Phone number is needed')
        
        profile = self.model(owner=owner, name=name, email=email, description=description, photo=photo, phone=phone)
        profile.save()
        return profile

class Realtor(models.Model):
    owner = models.OneToOneField(Users, related_name='Realtor', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    photo = models.ImageField(upload_to='photos/%Y/%m/%d/', blank=True, null=True)
    description = models.TextField(blank=True)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False, unique=True) 

    objects = RealtorManager()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

my serializer.py

```
class ProfileSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    owner = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(
        read_only=True, default=serializers.CurrentUserDefault())
    name = serializers.CharField(max_length=50)
    description = serializers.CharField(max_length=500)
    photo = serializers.ImageField(max_length=None, allow_empty_file=False, 
                                   use_url=settings.UPLOADED_FILES_USE_URL)
    phone = serializers.CharField(max_length=50)
    email = serializers.CharField(max_length=100)

    class Meta:
        model = Realtor
        fields = ['name', 'description', 'photo', 'phone', 'email', 'owner']

    def create(self, profile_data):
        return Realtor.objects.create_profile(**profile_data)
```

and finaly my views.py

```
class CreateProfile(CreateAPIView):
    parser_classes = (parsers.FormParser, parsers.MultiPartParser, parsers.FileUploadParser)
    renderer_classes = (renderers.JSONRenderer,)
    serializer_class = ProfileSerializer

    def post(self, request):
        profile = request.data
        serializer = self.serializer_class(data=profile, context={'request':request})
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        serializer.save()
        profile_data = serializer.data

        return Response(profile_data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
```

I keep getting this Error:

**RealtorManager.create_profile() missing 1 required positional argument: 'owner'**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to save the owner of the post when creating a post

if you want to save the post owner
as a logged-in user, you can do that like this...

```
class CreateProfile(CreateAPIView):
    parser_classes = (parsers.FormParser, parsers.MultiPartParser, parsers.FileUploadParser)
    renderer_classes = (renderers.JSONRenderer,)
    serializer_class = ProfileSerializer

    def post(self, request):
        profile = request.data
        serializer = self.serializer_class(data=profile, context={'request':request})
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        serializer.save(owner=request.user) # here save in database owner = request.user
        profile_data = serializer.data

        return Response(profile_data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
```